# How to loging to a website, that has password + captcha

Tags: python, cookies, request, captcha

i am writing a script that should look for new video releases from a private torrent tracker.

So the app is done, but i now need a way to get past the login screen, that has captcha, i have no idea how to do that.

Is there a way to use cookies from my own browser to get past login on the site, when i have credentials saved on my browser(firefox)?

Edit:

I am now trying to bypass the Captcha completely, by using cookies, i have an account to the site im trying to get in, and i read that it should be possible to bypass login and access a site by using cookies.

I found an example but i cannot get it to work. Here is the bit im trying to get to work:

```
cookies = {'uid': 'uid_here', 'pass': 'passkey', '__cfduid': 'cfduid'}

        try:
            page = requests.get(url, params=params, cookies=cookies).content
```

The cookies info i have copied form my own browser, but i cannot get this to work by myself

full bit of code im using as a refrence is here https://github.com/Flexget/Flexget/blob/97bcb6e10f654fbc5a3efa0bc00af6769d73ff69/flexget/plugins/sites/torrentday.py

edit2: heres what i have so far, but its not working:

```
def get_torrent(show_list):
    print('Starting torrent search...')
    new_eps = show_list
    file_name = "C:/Users/secret/Desktop/tv_torrents/ "
    start_url = "https://www.secretsite.com/browse.php?search="
    end_url = "&cata=yes"
    for line in new_eps:
        # search for *** releases for all series
        line += ' XAD'
        s_string = start_url + line + end_url
        cookies = {'site_cookie': 'ASDDA124fc96fb6776364asdA69c2f5ADAD921514234104'}
        try:
            read = requests.get(s_string, cookies=cookies).content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(read, 'lxml')
            links = soup.findAll('a')
            print(soup)
            torrent_links = ['https://www.secretsite.com/browse.php?search='
                             + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('torrent')]
        except RequestException as e:
            raise print('Could not connect to secretsite: %s' % e)
        else:
            try:
                for links in torrent_links:
                    r = request.urlretrieve(links, file_name)
                    print('Success!' + line + ' downloaded')
            except:
                print('failed to dl torrent for ' + line)
                pass
```

The documentation is not clear on how to "use" cookies, or i dont understand it:

> > > cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')
> > >
> > > r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

Comment: Having an issue with Captcha? Sounds like something is working exactly as it should be. Ideally, your session token will also be tied to other pieces of information like an IP address. Using the same session token from a new address _should_ again present the user with another challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, was just an formatting error.
Correct format for sending cookie data below:

```
cookies = {'uid': '232323', 'pass': '32323232323232323232323',
           '__cfduid': '2323232323adasdasdasdas78d6asdasjdgawi8d67as'}
try:
    page = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

This lets me get past the captcha and "login" to the site using cookies from my own browser where i have logged into the site already.

Answer (score 0):

for the captcha there is a python package that deals with it called [captcha2upload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/captcha2upload/0.1) , you will need a captcha solver account to get it (usually it's very cheap) just search in google for captcha solver.

I am not sure how you could use cookies for that matter...